# For loop iteration over selected numbers (not using range)

Tags: python, numpy, jupyter

This is an example code, but basically I am trying to select only a certain range of numbers, say 2, 4, and 6 and multiply the first axis of the 3D array of random values by first 2 then 4 and 6, and then store the new array (which should be still a size of 3, 30, and 10).
I keep getting this error though. What I'm doing is pretty simple, but I'm confused at what is wrong with my for loop? I originally tried np.array([2,4,6]) but I still got the same error.

```
data = np.random.rand(3,30,10)

data_new = np.zeros((data.shape))

for i in [2,4,6]:
    data_new[i,:,:] = data[i]*i

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_202420/2883607738.py in <module>
      4 
      5 for i in [2,4,6]:
----> 6     data_new[i,:,:] = data[i]*i
      7 

IndexError: index 4 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`data.shape[0]` that show you size of `first axis` and this size is `3` for this reason you can not call `data[4]` or `data_new[4]` and if you want `first axis`, try this:

```
for i in range(data.shape[0]):
    data_new[i] = data[i]*i
```

Or if you want select `first axis` and multiply to 2,4,6 ,... you need enumerate like below:

```
for idx, num in enumerate([2,4,6]):
    data_new[idx] = data[idx]*num
```

Comment: @wabash welcome dude have good time :))))

Answer (score 1):

I think you mean:

```
for i in [2,4,6]:
    data_new[:, :, i] = data[:, :, i]*i
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
data = np.random.rand(3,30,10)

data_new = data*np.array([2, 4, 6]).reshape(-1, 1, 1)
```

For example:

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.ones((3, 2, 2))
print(f'arr = \n{arr}')
arr_new = arr*np.array([2, 4, 6]).reshape(-1, 1, 1)
print(f'arr_new = \n{arr_new}')
```

Output:

```
arr = 
[[[1. 1.]
  [1. 1.]]

 [[1. 1.]
  [1. 1.]]

 [[1. 1.]
  [1. 1.]]]
arr_new = 
[[[2. 2.]
  [2. 2.]]

 [[4. 4.]
  [4. 4.]]

 [[6. 6.]
  [6. 6.]]]
```